# Laravel how to get value in <li> with button clicked and sent value to Controller

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

For each student I need to output his ID and button in my HTML,

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="findStudent" action="{{url('student/find')}}" method="POST">
          <ul>
            @foreach ($students as $student)
            <li>ID: {{ $student->sid }}<br></li>
            <div>
            <input id = "finding" type="submit"  value="Find Student" />
            </div> <br/>
          @endforeach
          </ul>
   </form>
```

And I want to get the value of sid that I clicked the corresponding button in my Controller:

```
public function find(Request $find){    
        $sid = $find->input('student');
        var_dump($sid);
}
```

But I got NULL, what's the problem?
Thank you, problem solved.

But if i have another function

```
   public function request(Request $request){

        $teacher_name = $request->input('teacher_name');

}
```

I want to get the $teacher_name in find, how could i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `<button>` element instead of `input` element:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="findStudent" action="{{url('student/find')}}" method="POST">
    <ul>
    @foreach ($students as $student)
        <li>ID: {{ $student->sid }}<br></li>
        <div>
            <button name="student" type="submit" value="{{ $student->sid }}">
                Find Student
            </button>
        </div>
        <br/>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
</form>
```

> Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_value.asp

Additionally, if you would like to use element id, you have to make it unique by concatenating student id to it:

```
<button id="finding{{ $student->sid }}" name="student" type="submit" value="{{ $student->sid }}">
```